# Is it possible to get access to variables inside function handles in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, function, handle

For example say I define:

```
c=3;
f = @(x) x + c;
```

is it possible to do

```
 f.c
```

or basically get access to the variables within the function handle?

I know I can make objects and structs in Matlab but the issue is that I have a .mat file with a bunch of functions and I would like to see the variables that they are using. In this specific scenario I am trying to avoid having to re-code my stuff by just accessing the variables in matlab but in cases where I don't have the option to re-code it would be nice to just have a way to access the variables/fields that define the function handle. I mean, when I call `f(3)` it returns `6` so it obviously knows about `c` somewhere, so how do I get access to that `c`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible, using the function [`functions`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html). Calling `F = functions(f)` returns a struct `F` with information about the function with handle `f`. When `f` is a handle to an [anonymous function](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), as in your case, one of the fields of `F` is `workspace`, which contains information about the variables required by the anonymous function:

```
>> c = 3;
>> f = @(x) x + c;
>> F = functions(f)
F = 
            function: '@(x)x+c'
                type: 'anonymous'
                file: ''
           workspace: {[1x1 struct]}
    within_file_path: '__base_function'
>> F.workspace{1}.c
ans =
     3
```